# Disable duplicate wifi networks on a Nokia G-0425G-A GPON

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

A few days ago I changed my ISP and the new one does not allow using my own GPON router or media converter. The provider wants their device to be the the one, connected to the optic cable, so I decided to give it a chance before disabling all its networks and use my own router.

The ISP's device is Nokia G-0425G-A and the technician gave me the credentials to the admin console so I have full access to it now.

I was scanning for networks around me to set it up and I discovered that it duplicates each radio which is not in the config - I have 1 SSID for 2.4 GHz radio and another 1 for the 5 GHz (with different SSIDs). But the router transmits one extra network with hidden SSID for each radio?!

I've played a lot with the settings but there isn't anything about it there. The only way I can stop the "hidden" network is to completely disable it's radio - 2.4 or 5 GHz. The hidden networks are still there even if I remove all SSIDs and just left the corresponding radio on...

I haven't seen behavior like this on any other router and I didn't find anything about it. I've talked with the ISP and they didn't know about the problem so they couldn't help me.

Do you know a way to disable the hidden networks? If you think like me that this is not a normal behavior, is there a channel I could submit a bug report to the vendor?

Comment: I've seen Huawei routers do this for automatic mesh building. I don't know how to disable it in your case but it's likely harmless.

Comment: Agree with @user1686 - the extra interface is for the WiFi Mesh (configurable in [Network → MESH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gweIw.jpg)). There doesn't seem to be a switch to turn it off from the web interface. However it shouldn't connect to anything until you add the serial number in the settings